# How to memorize a question?

Tags: support, feature-request, bookmarks

Suppose I have found a question that is important for me and the one I am about to refer to frequently.

How should I "memorize" it to my account so I will not need to search for it once again?

Comment: There's this newfangled technology called bookmarks or something like that ... Either that or just favourite it by clicking on the star.

Answer (score 5):

The feature already exists, it is called "Favoriting" a question.

You can learn more about them on the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) on Meta Stack Exchange.

But in short, you click the start underneath the voting buttons of the question

[image: Favorte Start Location]

And you can see them in your profile under the Favorites tab, and there is even a counter that will let you know how many updates were made to your favorite questions.

[image: Favorite Tab Location]